# ASP.NET MVC : display value in div

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I call an action method with a jquery post :

```
$('#selector').click(function (event) {
    var jqxhr = $.post("/MyController/MyAction", $("form").serialize(),
    function (data) {
        $('#myDIV').html(data); //ok here

        // Missing code, display text from my model in another div
    });
});
```

At "Missing code", I'd code to show a text (present in the model) in another div.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: Dont unsterstand what you are asking for :(

Comment: Why can't you do it the same way as you do it for the first div? (myDiv)

Comment: how does the mymodel looks like? are you passing mymodel to main view or the partial view?

Comment: @3nigma it's a partial view and the div I want refresh is not in this partial view

Comment: yes i understand that the div you want to refresh is not in the partial view but i wanted to ask is do you want to display data from the model that is passed to partial view(if you are passing a model in the partial view)?

Comment: @3nigma yes the model is passed to the partialview

Comment: ok, you can render the data from model property inside the partial view and hide that div or inpput whatever suits you then after doing `$('#myDIV').html(data); ` in the success call back find that div get its text and put it in the desired element like `var txt=$("#hiddenDivFromPartialView").html()` and `$("#yourDivID").html(txt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is in your model, create a hidden field to hold the data:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DataInModel)
```

Then just get the data from it:

```
$('#selector').click(function (event) {
    var jqxhr = $.post("/MyController/MyAction", $("form").serialize(),
    function (data) {
        $('#myDIV').html(data); //ok here

        // Missing code, display text from my model in another div
        $('#AnotherDiv').html($('#DataInModel').val())
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand right. The data that you receive form the ajax call don't contains the model data you are refferring to. I would suggest to extend the answer of your ajax call, maybe with a JSon answer.
something like

```
{ { myValue="<p>my html data</p>"} , {myValue = Model.CustomerID.ToString() }}
```

Thenk from your jQuery funciton call back you do something like (not tetset, just to give you and idea)

```
$.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
   if (index==0)
      $('#myDIV').html(optionData.myValue);
   else
      $('#myOtherDIV').html(optionData.myValue);
 }
```